# Why would Django localised template strings fail?

Tags: django, locale

I have a standard localised project set up. I have a couple of languages defined in my `settings.py`. I'm using `LocaleMiddleware`. I have a few `{%blocktrans%}` strings in my template file, which are getting pulled into my `django.po` file. I have run `django-admin.py compilemessages` and verified that the `.mo` file is created.

- There are no 'fuzzy' entries in the .po.
- In the template, `{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}` gives the correct language (in this case, `zh-cn`)
- I have restarted the [development] server
- I have `ENABLE_I18N = True` and `USE_L10N = True`
- I have set `LANGUAGE_CODE` and `LANGUAGES` in `settings.py`

When I render view, I know that the right locale is selected because view code that uses it (`request.session.get('django_language', settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)`) gets the right code. But the translations in the strings in the template just don't get shown.

How do I go about trying to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I'd missed something that was simultaneously obvious and not obvious. There are two different standards at work. Now I have fixed it, my settings file has:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', "English"),
    ('zh-CN', "中文")
)
```

But my locale directory is `locale/zh_CN`. I foolishly assumed the same locale standard would be used throughout Django localisation. I was wrong.

Further reading:

File where the hyphen type is used: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/global_settings.py

Docs where the underscore is used. Very last paragraph at the end of this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

I hate to ask this but, have you set `USE_I18N = True` in `settings.py` ?

Also you wrote `{%blocktranslate%}` in your question, whereas it should be `{% blocktrans %}`

Comment: Thanks, but sadly those only mistakes in typing question.

Answer (score 0):

Given all of that, the only things remaining are 1) the actual translation code is not being called at all (for some reason), or 2) it is bailing out before it gets its work done.

I keep a personal copy of Django around (i.e. not the system copy) so I can stick `print`'s deep in the guts of something. Try putting some `print`s  in `django/templatetags/i18n.py` and see if you are actually arriving in the right place.

Comment: That code is really hard to follow. Having a poke around there with pdb didn't do much to help sadly.

Comment: @Joe: Looking at the source for that file in Django 1.3.0, the class `BlockTranslateNode` has a method `.render()` at line 98. There are 2 invocations -- `translation.ungettext()` at line 110 and `translation.ugettext()` at 113 -- and that is where I would start investigating. If you aren't getting there at all, or if the parameters are wrong, then the problem is upstream (earlier in execution) from there, otherwise it's downstream. Good luck.

Comment: Don't worry I fixed it. Head-desk moment. Thanks for your help.